# Dataflow (Task Parallel Library) and async await

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, actor-model

Lets say I use the Dataflow blocks in .NET.
It is stated that "This dataflow model promotes actor-based programming"
Which is exaclty what I want to get at here.

However, if I process messages from, say a `BufferBlock<T>` and in the processor of the message, I decide to use `async`/`await`, this will fork out the execution to the current tread and a worker thread for the awaited task.

Is there any way to prevent concurrent execution within the actor/message processor here?

it's fine if the awaited task executes using non blocking IO ops with native callbacks.
But I'd really like to ensure that the any .NET code is only executed in sync.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to explain the answer with a concrete example. Can you post your code?

Comment: Fun fact: this was the very very early work on Akka.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This very much depends on how exactly will you process those messages.

If you use an `ActionBlock` with `async` `action`, don't set its `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` (which means the default value of 1 is used) and link it to the `BufferBlock`, then the `action` will execute for one message at a time, there will be no parallelism.

If you process the messages manually using a loop like this:

```
while (await bufferBlock.OutputAvailableAsync())
{
    var message = await bufferBlock.ReceiveAsync();
    await ProcessMessageAsync(message);
}
```

Then the messages will be processed one at a time too.

But in both cases, it doesn't mean that a message will be processed by a single thread. It may be processed by multiple threads, but not in parallel. This is because after `await`, the execution can resume on a different thread than where is was paused.

If you use some other way of processing messages (e.g. using the loop above, but omitting the `await` before `ProcessMessageAsync()`), then multiple messages could be processed concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what `await` does. It doesn't fork anything, it simply awaits for the result of an already asynchronous operation.

Methods marked with the `async` keyword do not automatically become asynchronous. It is only when an asynchronous operation is encountered inside the `async` method that execution continues asynchronously. The `async` keyword simply tells the compiler where execution should continue *after* the asynchronous operation completes.

No ThreadPool threads are wasted or harmed while awaiting so you shouldn't be trying to limit, prevent or circumvent this. In fact, you get better scalability when using asynchronous operations because the ThreadPool threads used by TPL Dataflow do not block waiting for long-running asynchronous operations like I/O or web service calls.

Comment: OK, bad wording on my part, lets assume the following example, my "actor" is processing a message from my bufferblock, in this processing, we hit an "await" statement, execution now returns to the caller, right? the rest of the code will be executed once the task completes. doesn't this open up for the processor to start processing a new message while the awaited task is also executing?

Comment: Not quite. ActionBlocks always execute their actions asynchronously respecting their execution options to limit the number of concurrent tasks. If you make another asynchronous call like [HttpClient.GetStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) without adding `await` execution will continue immediatelly. If you do add `await` execution will continue only after GetStringAsync completes

Comment: This does not work, I've tried it and the await block executes in a different thread than the message processor.

Comment: That's how the TPL in general works. What makes you think tis is a problem or that it "doesn't work"? The action's execution started in a ThreadPool thread anyway. When you call an asynchronous method with `await` it continues in another ThreadPool thread. When that finishes, the code after `await` will be executed in another thread. Any mixup will be caused only if you omit `await`: in this case both the asynchronous and the ActionBlock actions may run concurrently